# Variables in attributes on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, templates, attributes

I have a template called nonumericform.html.erb where I put a the fallowing code:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Plate</td><td><%= @field %></td></tr>
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
<tr><td><%= vehicle.plate %></td><%= vehicle.#{ @field } %> 
<td></td>             <td>_______________________________________</td></tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The controller pass 2 vars called @field and @vehicles to the template But i want to put the content of the var @field like a attribute of the var vehicle inside the loop. Can anyone help me. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `send`:

```
<%= vehicle.send(@field) %>
```

This will call whatever string in @field on the vehicle. Any additional arguments will get passed to the method as arguments.